# Form desconfigura DIV

Tags: css, laravel

Div não fica lado a lado depois que inseri os `{!! Form::` dentro da div row, as div COL ficam quebrados, um embaixo do outro em vez de lado a lado. é possível resolver isso ? ou é normal o Form fazer essa bagunça ?

> Bootstrap 4.1 - Laravel 5.5

```
<div class="row">

{!! Form::model($produto, ['route' => ['admin.produtos.update', $produto->id],   'class' => 'form-horizontal', 'method'  => 'post', 'autocomplete' => 'off']) !!}
    @include('backend.produtos.games.informacoes')
    <div class="card-footer">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">
            <i class="fa fa-save"></i> Atualizar Modificações
        </button>
        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
            <i class="fa fa-trash-alt"></i> Reiniciar
        </button>
    </div>
{!! Form::close() !!}

{!! Form::model($produto, ['route' => ['admin.produtos.updateMidia', $produto->id],   'class' => 'form-horizontal', 'method'  => 'post', 'autocomplete' => 'off']) !!}
    @include('backend.produtos.games.midia')

    <div class="card-footer">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">
            <i class="fa fa-save"></i> Salvar Imagem
        </button>
    </div>
{!! Form::close() !!}

</div>
```

**Código do Include com as divs-col**

```
<div class="col-lg-7">
 ...conteúdo...
</div>
```

**E no outro include**

```
<div class="col-lg-5">
...conteúdo...
</div>
```

Comment: Qual versão do Bootstrap vc está usando?

Comment: @hugocsl Bootstrap 4.1

Comment: Eu testei aqui colocando uma tag `<form>` normal e ficou alinhado um ao lado do outro... Mas tenta na div `<div class="card-footer">` colocar assim: `<div class="card-footer col-6">` ou então algo do tipo "'class' => 'form-horizontal col-6',"e ve se resolve

Comment: Tenta definir a largura da coluna na tag `<form>`

Comment: quando inclui na classe do form a classe col ela ajustou, porém a própria div col não preenche.. fica menor.. nem colocando col-7 e col-5 nas div de cada lado

Comment: Nessas divs de cada lado coloca a class `w-100` isso deve fazer ela ocupar 100% do width. Olha se resolve

Comment: não fez nada... tava diminuindo aqui o navegador.. quando muda a resolução.. fica certo.. mas quando fica na resolução acima de (min-width: 992px).. ele para de preencher

Comment: cara que loucura.. eu tirei a classe das divs laterais.. e passei pra classe dos 2 forms.. e voltou ao normal.. como se o form assumisse o lugar das divs

Comment: Mas resolveu então? Se não resolveu entra na página direto pelo browser. Aperta Ctrl+U, pega o código direto lá do browser com a página renderizada, incluindo essa div o forme e etc. Edita sua pergunta e coloca essa parte ai. Tem classe a mais ai ou div desnecessária to achando...

Comment: sim resolveu.. ta igual tava antes de eu colocar o form.. com as divis alinhadas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Michael conforme dito no comentário independente de ser um `form`, ou uma `div` ou uma `section` vc deve colocar as classes do *grid* do Bootstrap caso queira dividir os seus elementos em colunas.

Como no seu caso era o `form` que precisava ser alinhado e dividido dentro da `.row`, era ele que deveria receber a classe `col-xx`

Tipo: `'class' => 'form-horizontal col-lg-7',` para um `form` e `'class' => 'form-horizontal col-lg-5'`, no outro.

Aqui tem a documentação oficial do *grid* do BS4: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Comment: você tem razão kkk.. nem lebrava que você que deu a ideia.. se você não falasse eu ia demorar ou nem ia pensar em colocar a classe lá dentro do form.. o// vlw irmão obrigado! tamo junto!

Comment: @MichaelCosta tmj qq coisa estamos ai.